# Mercurial merging 2 branches, need to revert back

Tags: python, mercurial

I have a remote repository `MyProject` and within it have 3 modules `module1.py`, `module2.py` and `module3.py`.

```
+ MyProject
  - module1.py
  - module2.py
  - module3.py
```

Then to add a new feature created a new branch within the default branch and named it has `Myproject-newchanges` and changed `module2.py`.

```
+ MyProject-newchanges
  - module1.py
  - module2.py + NEW FEATURE.
  - module3.py
```

Inbetween, I started working on `module1.py` and `module3.py` on `MyProjects`.

Both these branches are pushed to the repository.

Now, in my default repository-MyProject in local directory I did a pull of `Myproject-newchanges` and merged with `Myproject` + `MyProject-NEWFEATURE`.

I have not committed it yet.

The problem now is the merge; it created a new copy of `module1.py`,`module2.py` and `module3.py` all from `MyProject-newchanges`. I lost all my latest change from `Myproject`'s `module1.py` and `module3.py`.

I need to do couple of things now,

1. Revert back to Myproject(Default) without Myproject-NEWFEATURE.
2. After 1) is successfull, I need a merge copy where I have module2.py-NEWFEATURE and module1.py & module3.py latest change..

I tried to explain my best.Hope its clear.

Comment: Sorry, it's not at all clear. "Created a new branch within the default branch and named it has `MyProject-newchanges`": do you mean that you cloned the repository to a new directory `Myproject-newchanges`?

Comment: If you can, show the output of `hg log -vl3`.

Comment: Yes, I did create a new directory Myproject-newchanges